Spring Boot Validation not Working for Patch Method
I have a "BookApp" Spring Boot Application. I want to make sure that null, blank, empty values cannot be passed to the fields of Book object. It works fine for createBook() and updateBook() methods, however, when it comes to patchBook() it does not work properly.

These are createBook(), updateBook() and patchBook() methods in BookServiceImpl.java:
    @Override
    public BookDto createBook(BookDto bookDTO) {
        Book book = bookMapper.bookDtoToBook(bookDTO);
        return bookMapper.bookToBookDto(bookRepository.save(book));
    }

    @Override
    public BookDto updateBook(Long id, BookDto bookDTO) {
        Book existingBook = bookRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Book not found with id: " + id));

        existingBook.setTitle(bookDTO.getTitle());
        existingBook.setAuthor(bookDTO.getAuthor());
        existingBook.setDescription(bookDTO.getDescription());

        Book updatedBook = bookRepository.save(existingBook);
        return bookMapper.bookToBookDto(updatedBook);
    }

    @Override
    public BookDto patchBook(Long id, Map<String, Object> updates) {
        BookDto existingBook = getBookById(id);

        if (updates.containsKey("title")) {
            existingBook.setTitle((String) updates.get("title"));
        }
        if (updates.containsKey("author")) {
            existingBook.setAuthor((String) updates.get("author"));
        }
        if (updates.containsKey("description")) {
            existingBook.setDescription((String) updates.get("description"));
        }

        return updateBook(id, existingBook);
    }



These are createBook(), updateBook() and patchBook() methods in BookController.java:
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<BookDto> createBook(@Valid @RequestBody BookDto bookDTO) {
    BookDto createdBook = bookService.createBook(bookDTO);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdBook);
}

@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<BookDto> updateBook(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody BookDto bookDTO) {
    BookDto updatedBook = bookService.updateBook(id, bookDTO);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedBook);
}

@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<BookDto> patchBook(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody Map<String, Object> updates) {
    BookDto patchedBook = bookService.patchBook(id, updates);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(patchedBook);
}


This is BookDto.java file
package az.edu.ada.wm2.BookApp.model.dto;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookDto {

    @NotBlank(message = "Title is required")
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Title must be less than 100 characters")
    private String title;

    @NotBlank(message = "Author is required")
    @Size(max = 50, message = "Author must be less than 50 characters")
    private String author;

    @NotBlank(message = "Description is required")
    @Size(max = 200, message = "Description must be less than 200 characters")
    private String description;
}



I tried to change the code for patchBook() in BookServiceImpl.java to this and it worked - it did not take null or empty values. However, with createBook() and updateBook() methods, when I tried to send those values, in postman, I used to get Bad Request, however, for patchBook(), I was getting internal server error. I do not get if it is normal or not (I am new to spring boot). Could you please help me to understand and fix this issue?
    @Override
    public BookDto patchBook(Long id, Map<String, Object> updates) {
        Book existingBook = bookRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Book not found with id: " + id));

        try {
            updates.forEach((key, value) -> {
                switch (key) {
                    case "title":
                        validateField("title", (String) value);
                        existingBook.setTitle((String) value);
                        break;
                    case "author":
                        validateField("author", (String) value);
                        existingBook.setAuthor((String) value);
                        break;
                    case "description":
                        validateField("description", (String) value);
                        existingBook.setDescription((String) value);
                        break;
                    // Add more fields here if needed
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid field: " + key);
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new ValidationException(e.getMessage());
        }

        Book updatedBook = bookRepository.save(existingBook);
        return bookMapper.bookToBookDto(updatedBook);
    }

    private void validateField(String fieldName, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fieldName + " cannot be null, empty, or blank");
        }
    }


Your patch method takes a Map not an object. There is nothing to validate on the Map hence it won't validate.
